# jQuery Mobile Table Reflow Headers with i18next translations

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, i18next

I want to use the code from [this page of the jQuery Mobile Demo site](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/table-reflow-stripes-strokes/) (jQuery Mobile 1.4.2) with the i18next translation tool, however the table headers disappear when viewing the table on mobile.

I understand jQM takes the header tag text and places it in front of the values for each row when the window is smaller than a certain threshold.

**I have built a demo [here](http://ptypix.com/demo)**. To view it in action, please change the width of your browser.

The top table has the intended behavior, but inline text for table headers, and the bottom table show the issue, where the i18n table headers appear correctly as One, Two, Three, Four on a wide screen, and they disappear on narrow screen.

**I'm looking for a way to use the i18n translations in the headers for mobile view, since it is already implemented across the rest of the site, and works beautifully.**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to `rebuild` the table after *translating* text.

Why? *table* widgets copies `thead`'s headers, adds them to `tbody` before content and hides them. On small screen, `thead` gets hidden and the copied headers are visible.

Upon translating, you only apply changes to `thead` headers but not the *hidden* ones in `tbody`.

```
i18n.init({
    preload: ['en', 'dev']
});
i18n.init({
    detectLngQS: 'lang'
});
i18n.init(function (t) {
    $("body").i18n();
    var appName = t("app.name");
    $("tableID").table("rebuild"); /* this */
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AxWau/)**